# How to give inputs as a parameter to an action method in MVC5?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an MVC5 app, and I have a view model defined like this:

```
public class RequestViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a state")]
    [Display(Name = "State")]
    public int StateID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a zip code")]
    [Display(Name = "Zip")]
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please choose a service")]
    [Display(Name = "Service")]
    public string ServiceName { get; set; }

    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }

    public string ImageMimeType { get; set; }

    public byte[] VideoData { get; set; }

    public string VideoMimeType { get; set; }
}
```

I'm calling this view model, from an action defined like this:

```
public ActionResult ServiceRequest(RequestViewModel rvm, HttpPostedFileBase image = null, HttpPostedFileBase video = null)
{
    ...
}
```

So, the point is that in my _Layout.cshtml file I have two input fields, and an "a href", and the thing is when someone presses the object containing the href, I want to take the input of those two fields, and call the above action method. Here is the part from my _Layout.cshtml.

```
<div class="input-top">
     <a href='@Url.Action("ServiceRequest", "Home", new { rvm.ZipCode = homeZipCode, rvm.ServiceName = homeService })'><img src="~/Content/img/GOBtn.png" class="gobtn-position"></a>
     <input id="homeZipCode" type="text" class="form-control input-position-2" placeholder="ZIP">
     <input id="homeService"  type="text" class="form-control input-position-1" placeholder="What do you need done today?">
</div>
```

I wrote a code like this one, but it shows me error in the part of new `{ rvm.ZipCode = homeZipCode, rvm.ServiceName = homeService }`, and I can see that the point is that rvm is not defined anywhere in my _Layout.cshtml file, and therefore it cannot resolve the ZipCode and ServiceName attributes. Any idea, how can I pass the values of those two input fields to my action method?

Comment: Is `ServiceRequest()` a GET or POST?

Comment: I have both GET and POST versions of that action method.

Comment: An action link is a GET but you have included your POST method. Is your GET method `public ActionResult ServiceRequest(string homeZipCode, string homeService)`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can define a click handler for anchor tag and pass an Ajax request with the data. It would be easier.

So for example:

- Controller:

  ```
  public class ServiceController : Controller    {

  public ActionResult ServiceRequest()
  {
      return View();
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult ServiceRequest(RequestViewModel rvm, HttpPostedFileBase image = null, HttpPostedFileBase video = null)
  {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
  }}
  ```
- Sample View

> ```
> @{
>     ViewBag.Title = "Index";
> }
>
> <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
> ```

```
<div class="input-top">
     <a class="Gobtn" href="#"><img src="~/Content/themes/base/images/ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png" /></a>
     <input id="homeZipCode" type="text" class="form-control input-position-2" placeholder="ZIP">
     <input id="homeService"  type="text" class="form-control input-position-1" placeholder="What do you need done today?">
</div>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a.Gobtn').on('click', function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            alert('here in');

            debugger;
            // Send an ajax post request with data

            var homeZipCode = $("#homeZipCode").val();
            var homeService = $("#homeService").val();

            var model = { ZipCode: homeZipCode, ServiceName: homeService };

            $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("ServiceRequest", "Service")',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    data: JSON.stringify(model)
                })
                .success(function(result) {
                });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: If I keep the url part as in your answer, it cannot find it, because it tries to resolve the current url: https://localhost:44300/@Url.Action(%22ServiceRequest%22,%20%22Home%22) , but if I change it to /Home/ServiceRequest, then I get another error in console saying no element found. Any idea?

Comment: @ett - Sorry could not get back to you on time. Are you still facing this issue? The code I provide works well for me with action signature in your original post.

Comment: Yes, I have the problem written in my above comment. Any idea?

Comment: @ett - I am not sure why you are facing the issue. Seems some reference or js problem. I am updating full code which is working on my machine, see if it helps.

Comment: Maybe because the view in question in my code is the _Layout.cshtml file?

Comment: Okay, now I get an error message saying: POST https://localhost:44300/Home/ServiceRequest [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 4ms]

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code for tag `a`

```
<a href='@Url.Action("ServiceRequest", "Home", new { homeZipCode = Model.ZipCode, homeService = Model.ServiceName })'><img src="~/Content/img/GOBtn.png" class="gobtn-position"></a>

'rvm' has no meaning here....
```

Comment: I'm inside my _Layout, so you can assume that I have no Model assigned to it.

Answer (score 0):

You must Add name attribute for your inputs like :

```
<div class="input-top">

 <input id="homeZipCode" name="ZipCode /*Your property Name*/" ...>
 <input id="homeService" name="ServiceName"  ...>
<input type="submit" value="ServiceRequest">
</div>
```

Or use html helpers for it

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ZipCode)
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ServiceName)
    <input type="submit" value="ServiceRequest">
}
```